# Arrays being reset in JUnit 4

Tags: java, arrays, junit, junit4

I'm testing code for a variety of insertion sort implementations using JUnit but after each test, certain values in arrays are resetting. To explain I need to find the run times (in my test cases) of each implementation of insertion sort I've created. Basically I start a stop watch, call the sort, stop the timer and I'm to save that value (the execution time) into an object then save that to an array of said objects. This code is shown below:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SortTest 
{       

    private static double seconds16;
    private static double seconds256;
    private static double seconds4096;
    private static StopWatch time = new StopWatch();
    private static Word[] sort16 = new Word[3];
    private static Word[] sort256 = new Word[3];
    private static Word[] sort4096 = new Word[3];

    @Test
    public void testSortInsert() 
    {
        Word[] expectedFirst = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getFirstArray());
        Word[] resultFirst = TextFilesArrays.getFirstArray();

        time.start();
        Insertion.sortInsert(resultFirst);
        time.stop();
        seconds16 = time.getTime();
        sort16[0] = new Word("SortInsert", (int)seconds16);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedFirst, resultFirst);


        Word[] expectedSecond = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getSecondArray());
        Word[] resultSecond = TextFilesArrays.getSecondArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortInsert(resultSecond);
        time.stop();
        seconds256 = time.getTime();
        sort256[0]  = new Word("SortInsert", (int)seconds256);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedSecond, resultSecond);


        Word[] expectedThird = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getThirdArray());
        Word[] resultThird = TextFilesArrays.getThirdArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortInsert(resultThird);
        time.stop();
        seconds4096 = time.getTime();
        sort4096[0] = new Word("SortInsert", (int)seconds4096);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedThird, resultThird);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertComparable()
    {
        Word[] expectedFirst = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getFirstArray());
        Word[] resultFirst = TextFilesArrays.getFirstArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortComparable(resultFirst);
        time.stop();
        seconds16 = time.getTime();
        sort16[1]  = new Word("SortComparable", (int)seconds16);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedFirst, resultFirst);

        Word[] expectedSecond = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getSecondArray());
        Word[] resultSecond = TextFilesArrays.getSecondArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortComparable(resultSecond);
        time.stop();
        seconds256 = time.getTime();
        sort256[1] = new Word("SortComparable", (int)seconds256);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedSecond, resultSecond);

        Word[] expectedThird = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getThirdArray());
        Word[] resultThird = TextFilesArrays.getThirdArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortComparable(resultThird);
        time.stop();
        seconds4096 = time.getTime();
        sort4096[1] = new Word("SortComparable", (int)seconds4096);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedThird, resultThird);
    }   

    @Test
    public void testInsertBinary()
    {
        Word[] expectedFirst = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getFirstArray());
        Word[] resultFirst = TextFilesArrays.getFirstArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortBinary(resultFirst);
        time.stop();
        seconds16 = time.getTime();
        sort16[2] = new Word("SortBinary", (int)seconds16);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedFirst, resultFirst);

        Word[] expectedSecond = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getSecondArray());
        Word[] resultSecond = TextFilesArrays.getSecondArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortBinary(resultSecond);
        time.stop();
        seconds256 = time.getTime();
        sort256[2] = new Word("SortBinary", (int)seconds256);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedSecond, resultSecond);

        Word[] expectedThird = TextFilesArrays.expectedSort(TextFilesArrays.getThirdArray());
        Word[] resultThird = TextFilesArrays.getThirdArray();
        time.start();
        Insertion.sortBinary(resultThird);
        time.stop();    
        seconds4096 = time.getTime();
        sort4096[2] = new Word("SortBinary", (int)seconds4096);
        time.reset();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedThird, resultThird);
    }
```

Now what happens is during the first test, the values of `sort16[0]`, `sort256[0]`, and `sort4096[0]` are all set to the appropriate run time (as a Word object (String a, int b)). The problem I'm having is that upon the next test starting, the int portion of `sort16[0]` is reset to "0" then all respective values of `sortXXXX[1]` are set correctly. Lastly when the third test begins, the int portion of `sort16[1]` AND the int portion of `sort256[1]` is set to zero. Making the final arrays incorrect being:

`sort16 = { (Word(String x, int 0)), (Word(String x, int 0)), (Word(String x, int x)) }`
`sort256 = { (Word(String x, int x)), (Word(String x, int 0)), (Word(String x, int x)) }`
`sort4056 = { (Word(String x, int x)), (Word(String x, int x)), (Word(String x, int x))}`

Where "x" is the correct value. I'm completely confused as to why these values are being set to 0 in this way and any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: I've noticed that none of the values in the arrays are correct. In the code directly above, the "x's" are not the correct value. Instead they changed to a random smaller int like "24" when some should be (for example) "17000".

Comment: Also another thing. I have to use the StopWatch() method to keep track of the time of each sort but I'm not 100% sure if I'm using it correctly. When I run the program the time for the smaller sorts of 16 is sometimes slower than the larger sorts of 256. For example the time to sort the 16 elements takes 1 second but the time to sort 256 elements is 0.5 seconds. Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't happen to have static fields in your `Word` class by mistake? That can cause unexpected changes of values... On the whole, I'm afraid this question is unanswerable, since we don't have enough information to reproduce the issue nor truly understand the cause. Try working on a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: No there is no static field on the Word class. I know the question doesn't provide a lot of detail on what exactly is going on making the problem difficult to replicate. I was just hoping that maybe some one has some previous knowledge of JUnit "acting strange" and potentially changing values on `@Test` calls. I'm assuming the problem might just lie in somewhere I'm changing the arrays without noticing it. I'm going to look into it more tomorrow. Also I can provide you with the rest of the code to make the tests run if you'd like, (it's only 3 other files (200 lines of code)).

Comment: A reproducible problem will certainly help you get an answer. But 200 lines of code is too many for an SO question. You need to focus on stripping down your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. For instance, the example you provided has lots of timing-related code, yet the problem you describe only relates to the contents of your arrays. Do you need three tests to prove the problem or is two enough? Strip anything that doesn't affect the outcome, then add that code to your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.